# UITableViewCell Contact's app like

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

how can i create this kind of UITableViewCell where i can also set type of given string (for example email home, work, other)

[image]

I achieved something like this so far

[image]

Comment: The answer to question would altogether be an entire application. There is no sure shot way of doing what you are trying to achieve. However, if you ask some specific questions, that can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a UITableViewCell subclass and add UI elements yourself (either in code or in interface builder).
There are a lot of tutorials out there about how to do that. (e.g. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702)